# characteristic function problem 4

Tags: probability-distributions

which of the following is not a characteristic function?

a) 1

b) $e^{it} $ , $t \in R$

c) $\frac{1}{1-it} $, $t\in R$

d)$e^{|-t|}$, $t \in R$

Comment: This looks like it is copied from a textbook.  Where are you stuck on this exercise? We want to help you do it; we might not want to do it in your stead.

Comment: We know that if f(t) is characteristic function then it is even function. It seems a) & d) are right answers. If we use the property that f(t)=o then all the responses are correct. Is there any general way to find which function is characteristic function.